# Foundation datepicker - disabling future dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using [foundation datepicker](http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html#docs) and I am trying to disable dates. I am able to disable dates for one field, where dates are disabled from week ago, but I am not able to disable dates that are going from now into the future:

```
onRender: function (date) {
   return date.valueOf() > date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
}
```

This is the complete code:

```
var date = new Date();
var weekBack = new Date(new Date(date).setDate(date.getDate() - 7));

$('#datePicker').fdatepicker({
    closeButton: false,
    initialDate: weekBack,
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() > weekBack.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
      },
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
           var dateFrom = $("#datePicker").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");
           var dateTo = $("#datePicker1").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");
           timelines(dateFrom, dateTo);
           barCharts(dateFrom, dateTo);
  });

  $('#datePicker1').fdatepicker({
      closeButton: false,
      initialDate: date,
      format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
      onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() > date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
      },
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
           var dateFrom = $("#datePicker").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");
           var dateTo = $("#datePicker1").val().split(".").reverse().join("-");
           timelines(dateFrom, dateTo);
           barCharts(dateFrom, dateTo);
  });
```

Comment: I can't find the `maxDate` in foundation datepicker options as in jQuery datepicker. You can have a hidden second datepicker and set the initial date to todays date. In the first datepicker if user selects date greater than today's date you can show message that future dates are not allowed. http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html#no-inputs-example

Comment: But I need second datepicker to be disabled for future dates from start, so this solution unfortunately doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, it can. In your question consider the second date picker element as the first datepicker and you will have one more third (hidden) datepicker and the second will rely on this third datepicker by which you can limit the max date to today. But this is just a work around I guessed. Good luck finding a solution though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just set the endDate as following:

```html
var now = new Date();    
$("#birthday").fdatepicker({
                format: "dd M yyyy",
                endDate: now
            });
```

Conversely, if you want to disable the past days, set the startDate:

```html
var now = new Date();
$("#checkin").fdatepicker({
                format: "dd M yyyy",
                startDate: now
            });
```

Hope this useful!

Comment: how do we disable date and enable time pick only ?

Comment: @ZameerFouzan you can set the option {format: 'hh:ii'}

Answer (score -1):

can that help you?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/D9C4F/

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/39753-foundation-datepicker-select-end-date
```

and that as well?

```
http://app.thewatchenthusiast.com/themes/base/bower_components/foundation-datepicker/example.html
```